# Limit text (not including HTML) in contenteditable html editor

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to limit characters inside contenteditable div that is an HTML editor.
I need to limit to N (1500) characters not including HTML.

So i came up with this for now:

```
 $(".minieditor-content").bind('click', function (event) {
                var length = $(".minieditor-content").text().length;
                if (length > 1499) {
                    angular.element(".minieditor-content").html(html_substr($(".minieditor-content").html(), 1499));
                }
            });

            function html_substr  (str, count) {

                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = str;

                walk(div, track);

                function track(el) {
                    if (count > 0) {
                        var len = el.data.length;
                        count -= len;
                        if (count <= 0) {
                            el.data = el.substringData(0, el.data.length + count);
                        }
                    } else {
                        el.data = '';
                    }
                }

                function walk(el, fn) {
                    var node = el.firstChild;
                    do {
                        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                            fn(node);
                            //          Added this >>------------------------------------<<
                        } else if (node.nodeType === 1 && node.childNodes && node.childNodes[0]) {
                            walk(node, fn);

                        }
                    } while (node = node.nextSibling);
                }
                return div.innerHTML;
            }
```

Which works great. The only problem is that if I type more characters over the limit, after their deletion, the cursor moves to the begining of the paragraph and it lets you type, then it removes the end of the paragraph.
Maybe Substringing is that the best choice. What are your recommendations/tweaks to my code to make it work?

Thanks